# Sequentiality or Sequentialism?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The below sentence sounds perfectly reasonable:

```
"Parallelism is ensured by using A and B"
```

How can one make the same sentence using sequential in place of parallel?

```
"Sequentialism is ensured by using A and B"
```

OR

```
"Sequentiality is ensured by using A and B"
```

Google gives more hits for "sequentiality", but "sequentialism" sounds better to me. Both are rejected by my spell checker.

Which one is correct? What is an alternative (better) word to use in this context?

**TLDR:** `Parallel:Parallelism --> Sequential:?`

Comment: First, forget spell checker. It's good for typos, but useless for word choice, content, etc. And rather than googling a term to see how many hits you get (everyone's webpage), better to use Ngram to search edited and published materials. But, Ngram also shows a  definite preference for "sequentiality," so you may be stuck with that. You might try, e.g., "A sequential structure is ensured ...," but when a word becomes part of the jargon of a particular field (not sure what in what context you want to use these words), how it sounds to you is less important than how it sound to everyone else.

Comment: For almost all "normal" contexts it would be better to use the "normal" word **sequence**. More obscure derived forms may "established usage" in certain domain-specific contexts - but I don't know those contexts, so to me, both *sequentiality* and *sequentialism* sound like either jargon or ignorant usages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sequentialism* appears as a term of art in various fields with the connotation of a system or an ideology.

In politics: Andrew Janos in his book *Politics an Paradigms* uses the word to describe the argument made in Lenin's today to describe the belief that Russia would have to go through the sequence of societal states that Marx prescribed for industrial countries instead of jumping from the semi-feudal to the socialistic.  (Janos indexes the word *sequentialism* without using it the referenced text.)

In education, pejoratively:  from *[Humanisic Frontiers in American Education](https://books.google.com/books?id=qKbZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sequentialism%22&dq=%22sequentialism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8mp7Mw73JAhUFGz4KHdDzAPQQ6AEISTAI)* by R. P. Fairfield.

> **Sequentialism** -— the notion that there is, if we could only find it, one right linear order in which things can best be learned or
>   done: The myth is that in each compartment of knowledge there are
>   "fundamentals," that step one must precede [others].

In paleontology:  from *[Life: its nature, varieties, and phenomena. Also, Times and seasons](https://books.google.com/books?id=nowEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22sequentialism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM-NrWy73JAhWJFT4KHWbpB7cQ6AEIRjAI#v=onepage&q=%22sequentialism%22&f=false)* by Leopold Hartley Grindon:

> Doubtless, too, every shape of organized existence had its own special
>   era of commencement, as illustrated in the **sequentialism** of the
>   fossils beneath our feet.

In computing, in contrast to computations done in parallel: from the *[Third IEEE International Symposium on Object-Oriented Real-Time Distributed Computing](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZTRRAQAAIAAJ&q=%22sequentialism%22&dq=%22sequentialism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_h-SHzb3JAhUIFT4KHeU8CB84KBDoAQhEMAk)* (2000):

> An examination of the recursive NE [Newton-Euler] equations of [the
>   combined linear and rotational] motion [of rigid bodies] shows a
>   certain amount of parallelism with a large amount of **sequentialism**
>   in the flow of computation.

If your context coincides with or is (ahem) parallel to these uses, then the *-ism* form might be appropriate; otherwise, stick with the other nominalization.

Answer (score 1):

[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sequential) suggests sequentiality.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to rewrite the sentence by substituting one word for the other you will lose semantical meaning.
Parallelism and Sequentialism are not the the same things so you'll have to use the notion of Sequentialism depending on what it is you're trying to present.

A and B going together  - parallelism
B flowing from/following/deriving from A - sequentialism

Or you can say that 
"Sequentialism is ensured by B being predicated by A" - that will keep your the style intact and will still be notionally sound.

And I agree with "Sequentialism" as a noun here. 
Sequentiality is a product/result or even qualitative distinction of applying Sequentialism as a tool/means to whatever process/linear argument you're working with

That's my two penny-worths.
Thanks for the question.